# Slf4j and logback in an eclipse PDE project?

Tags: java, eclipse, logback, pde

I have added slf4j 1.6.1, logback-core-0.9.24.jar,  and logback-classic-0.9.24.jar to my target platform and added them as a dependency in the MANIFEST file in a plug-in project.

In the Activator I do:

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Activator.class
      .getName());

  private static Activator defaultInstance;

  public Activator() {
    Activator.defaultInstance = this;
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see
   * org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext )
   */
  public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(logger.isInfoEnabled());
    System.out.println(logger.isDebugEnabled());
    System.out.println(logger.isWarnEnabled());
    System.out.println(logger.isErrorEnabled());
    logger.info("llllladasdad");
  }
  }
}
```

but it just prints false for all cases and nothing for the info call. How do I enable logback in an eclipse PDE project?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force the logback configuration, reseting the default config to load your own XML config file. The code to do that is described in [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/joran.html).